# rbenv install gives ": No such file or directory" on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: ruby, bash, ubuntu, rbenv

**Apologia**

This seems like a pretty obvious problem...and I'm sure it's a duplicate...I've actually searched around my filesystem and the web for this, but haven't yet come across an answer for "rbenv" itself.

**Context**

I tried to install rbenv on my ubuntu 14.04 machine per this link: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-ruby-on-rails-with-rbenv-on-ubuntu-14-04

```
cd
git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
echo 'eval "$(rbenv init -)"' >> ~/.bashrc

git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/ruby-build.git ~/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build
echo 'export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/plugins/ruby-build/bin:$PATH"' >> ~/.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

**Problem**

When .bashrc runs ~/.rbenv/bin/rbenv ,it gets this error:

```
: No such file or directory
```

I get the same error when I run it directly:

```
~/.rbenv$  rbenv init -
```

**Checked this**

I've checked the script; the first line "#!/usr/bin/env bash" looks ok.

However, I'm not sure at what point it's failing. Short of adding a bunch of "echo's" to the script, I didn't have an easy way to debug it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you using zsh? because in that case you should repeat those steps using ~/.zshrc

Comment: Nope: /etc/password has my shell as  "/bin/bash"

Comment: check you current shell typing `echo $0`.

Comment: "echo $0" outputs "bash"

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you cloned the repo to somewhere other than ~/.rbenv?

`git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git .rbenv`
should be
`git clone git://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv.git ~/.rbenv`